# mySQL Distinct Join?

Tags: mysql, left-join, distinct

I have the following database structure

```
table_1
  text_1 (INT)
  text_2 (INT)


i18n
  id_i18n (PK INT)
  locale  (PK VARCHAR(5))
  text    (TEXT)
```

On table_1, the columns text_1 and text_2 are foreign keys pointing to some i18n.id_i18n entries.
I can easily join the entries for a specific locale

```
SELECT t1.text as text_1, t2.text as text_2
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN i18n as t1 ON text_1 = t1.id_i18n and t1.locale = "en_us"
LEFT JOIN i18n as t2 ON text_2 = t2.id_i18n and t2.locale = "en_us"
```

I can also get the following

```
row1: locale, text_1, text_2
row2: locale, text_1, text_2
row3: locale, text_1, null
row4: locale, text_1, text_2
```

using this query

```
SELECT t1.text as text_1, t2.text as text_2
FROM room
LEFT JOIN i18n as t1 ON text_1 = t1.id_i18n
LEFT JOIN i18n as t2 ON text_2 = t2.id_i18n and t1.locale = t2.locale
group by t1.locale;
```

assuming the I have the following i18n entries

```
      id_i18n   locale  text
row1: 1         en_us   text_1_for[en_us]
row2: 1         en_gb   text_1_for[en_gb]
row3: 1         el_gr   text_1_for[el_gr]
row4: 2         en_us   text_2_for[en_us]
row5: 2         en_gb   text_2_for[en_gb]
row6: 2         pr_pk   text_2_for[pr_pk]
row7: 1         en_ca   text_1_for[en_ca]
```

and then a table that links to those named tbl

```
     id, i18n_text_1, i18n_text_2
row1 1   1            2
```

I want to produce a result set like

```
      locale,  text_1,              text_2
row1: en_us    text_1_for[en_us]    text_2_for[en_us]
row2: en_gb    text_1_for[en_gb]    text_2_for[en_gb]
row3: el_gr    text_1_for[el_gr]    null
row4: pr_pk    null                 text_2_for[pr_pk]
row5: en_ca    text_1_for[en_ca]    null
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: What do you mean by *"all existing locales for both columns"*? Could you clarify your question a bit more? Perhaps provide some sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT     a.locale, c.text AS text_1, d.text AS text_2
FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT locale FROM i18n) a
CROSS JOIN table_1 b
LEFT JOIN  i18n c ON b.text_1 = c.id_i18n AND a.locale = c.locale
LEFT JOIN  i18n d ON b.text_2 = d.id_i18n AND a.locale = d.locale
```

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae650/7/0)

---

**EDIT**: This might work better:

```
SELECT
    a.locale, b.text_1, c.text_2
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT locale FROM i18n) a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT b.locale, b.text AS text_1
    FROM   table_1 a
    JOIN   i18n b ON a.text_1 = b.id_i18n
) b ON a.locale = b.locale
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT b.locale, b.text AS text_2
    FROM   table_1 a
    JOIN   i18n b ON a.text_2 = b.id_i18n
) c ON a.locale = c.locale
```

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae650/11/0)

Comment: Adding a GROUP BY locale at the end made it work like a charm! You're a genius. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Virus, hmm okay, I'm assuming you don't care which `text_1 -> text_2` combination is returned with the particular `locale` then. Regardless, glad to hear it works for you!

Comment: I just validated a resultset completely and it appears adding GROUP BY is not such a good idea. Withought the GROUP BY I get all combinations (cartesian product). Any suggetions on how to fix that?

Comment: @Virus, if you only want one `text_1 -> text_2` combination per `locale`, which combination do you want? The only way you can represent all `text_1 -> text_2` combinations for each locale is to have the combinations repeated for each locale. Can you please provide some sample data and your expected desired result?

Comment: @Virus, Thanks for posting your data. I see what you mean now; I'm formulating a solution for you now.

Comment: @Virus take a look at this [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae650/7/0). It works perfectly in accordance with your example result set, but it assumes you only have one row in `table_1`. Does that work for you? If not, please post a more accurate representation of your sample data.

Comment: @Virus two potential solutions now posted with corresponding SQLFiddle demos. Please let me know if either of them work or don't work.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a million Zane. You rock! :D

Comment: @Jane the first solution with the cross join is incredible faster than the second one. Second one took around 0.048 whereas cross join took only 0.001 :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you do

```
SELECT text
  FROM table_1
  JOIN i18n ON i18n_title = i18n.id_i18n OR i18n_name = i18n.id_i18n
```

Comment: I want to get all the i18n related columns in a single query and don't want to mix the results. So, correct result would be row1: text_1{locale, text} text_2{locale,text}, row2: text_1{locale, text} text_2{locale, text}, etc. and of course null when there's no text for that locale ;)

Comment: select sd.locale, sd.text as short_descr, ld.text as long_text
    FROM room
    LEFT JOIN i18n as sd ON i18n_short_descr = sd.id_i18n
    LEFT JOIN i18n as ld ON i18n_short_descr = ld.id_i18n
    group by sd.locale;