# Mysql - join 2 queries with limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Im not very familiar with using 'join' in queries. I really tried solving this by my own, but it seems to be too hard.

I got 2 Tables:

```
Table 'users':
+-----------------+-----------------+
|     member      |     online      |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| mahran          |               1 | 
| peter           |               1 |
| Jen             |               1 |
| Steve           |               0 |
+-----------------+-----------------+

Table 'tickets'
+-----------------+----------------+----------------+
|      name       |    category    |      time      |
+-----------------+----------------+----------------+
| mahran          | silver         |              1 |
| peter           | blue           |              1 |
| mahran          | blue           |              2 |
| peter           | red            |              3 |
| peter           | green          |              2 |
| Jen             | silver         |              1 |
+-----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

**The chellange:**
I need each member (users.member) who's online (users.online). The next thing is to get the category for each member (user.member = tickets.name) with the highest time (probably ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1).

**So, for example:**
Peter is online. Peters highest time is 3 at the position of category=red. So I want peter to show up in the result with his category 'red'. Mahran would show up with blue. Jen would get silver. And steve would be left out because he's not online.

I hope this was clear. In general I know how the queries would look like but theres no chance for me merging them together.

What needs to be merged:

```
SELECT member FROM users WHERE online = 1;
|
v for each member
SELECT category FROM tickets WHERE name=users.member ORDER BY time DESC.
```

So, any ideas how to solve this?

Here is a fiddle with a not working query: [Click](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1832d2/2)

Comment: join with member is not an good idea. use primary key and foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT U.member
    ,T.category
FROM users U
INNER JOIN tickets T ON T.name = U.member
INNER JOIN (SELECT T2.name
               ,MAX(T2.time) AS [maxTime]
           FROM tickets T2
           GROUP BY T2.name) AS M ON M.name = T.name
                               AND M.maxTime = T.time
WHERE U.online = 1
```

The use of [name] to join the two tables is not a good practice, it's much better to use keys instead. But my query is just here to help you understanding the process of jointure.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Solved my question and also the fastest processed query (not unimportant when using a database with over 50k entries). Thanks.

Comment: @C4ud3x Thank you for your feedback on the performance, i knew that it was a difference but two times faster is huge! The cause is very simple to understand, with a jointure you only get once the max value for each member instead of querying once for each rows of the table.

Comment: Yeah I was also surprised about the processing-time. Gordon's solution took about 24ms, yours only 12ms (tested multiple times) by using a ticket-table with 55600 entries. Thank you for explaining in detail. Im just about getting into using join for my queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with a correlated subquery:

```
select u.member,
       (select t.category
        from tickets t
        where t.name = u.member
        order by t.time desc
        limit 1
       ) as MostRecentCategory
from users u
where u.online = 1;
```

This can make use of the following indexes:  `users(online, member)` and `ticket(member, time, category)`.

Comment: It's working but in term of performance it's not optimal, your subquery is going to be executed for each row of the table [users]

Comment: @JoëlSalamin: I checked out the performance. You are right. Your query is twice times faster. Changed the solution-marker.

Comment: @C4ud3x . . . Are you using the composite index that is recommended?  Executing the subquery should be a simple index lookup, and that is can be much faster than the sort that MySQL uses for `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly

```
 SELECT DISTINCT users.member, tickets.category FROM tickets JOIN users ON users.member = tickets.name WHERE users.online = 1 ORDER BY tickets.time DESC
```

Comment: With this I got the same member showing up multiple times. I only want to show up every member only 1 time with his category at the highest time.

Comment: Im building up a fiddle with the tables. Should be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sql fiddle?

```
USE DISTINCT
```

[stackoverflow.com/questions/11704012/mysql-distinct-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704012/mysql-distinct-join)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT User.member,Ticket.category FROM users AS USER
INNER JOIN tickets AS Ticket ON (User.member = Ticket.name)
WHERE User.online = 1;
```

Comment: It outputs the hole table 'tickets'. Check the fiddle I posted on the bottom of the question and try out your query by your own.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but peter seems to be RED, It's time is 3. Don't you?

Depending on table definition, is not guaranteed to have one only result for each user.
For example, if peter has time 3 in two categories, you can get one different category depending of the SQL sorting method.

To be sure, tickets.Category and tickets.time must be in a unique key (both toghether, not a unike key for each field)

Assuming that, the Query could be this.

```
select t2.name,  t2.category
from
tickets t2
INNER JOIN (Select
        u.member, max(time)
        from users u, tickets t
        where
        u.member = t.name
        and u.online = 1
        group by u.member
       ) as usermaxtime on t2.name = usermaxtime.member;
```

Comment: Avoid using this old school syntax for joining two tables together, use `INNER` clause instead

Comment: My fault, sorry. Sure, peters category should show up as red. Joël's solution is still correct.

Comment: Be sure about my comment about two or more categories with the same time on the same member.

Comment: @Biggum: This constelation is not possible in my system. No need to worry about.